# Showing percent difference in values in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table and in Column 1 is a list of companies, and company names may appear more than once because Column 2 is a year. Column 3 is the amount a company spent in that respective year. How can I show the percent differences between each year without spilling into the next company? For instance Company, A is 2017-2020 and i want to show the % growth for that. But the next row is Company B for 2017-2020 and I don't want to calculate the % between the values for 2020 Company A and 2017 Company B.

Comment: Can you include a couple of records for a visual example?

Answer (score 2):

**To calculate the % between the values for different companies:**

1. [Sort the data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654) by company.
2. [Find the percentage of the amount](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-percentages-6b5506e9-125a-4aba-a638-d6b40e603981). Select the cell. Click Home > Number Format > Percentage. Enter the formula in cell C2: =B2/A2.
3. [Find the percentage of change between two amounts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-percentages-6b5506e9-125a-4aba-a638-d6b40e603981). Select the cell. Click Home > Number Format > Percentage. In cell B3, divide the company A's second year’s sales by the first year, and then subtract 1, or enter the formula in cell C3. =(B2/A2)-1.

Read more about calculating percentages at [support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-percentages-6b5506e9-125a-4aba-a638-d6b40e603981).
Hope it helps, Please upvote!

Comment: Please include relevant content, not links, as links go stale and are more dificult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Pivot Table for this:

[image]

As you can see, `Company A` invested 1000 on 2017 and 2000 on 2018. So `2000-1000=1000` and '1000 / 2017 investment (which is 1000)= 100%'

`Company A` invested 3000 on 2019 and 2000 on 2018. So `3000-2000=1000` and '1000 / 2018 investment (which is 2000)= 50%'

And so on.

About Pivot Tables, check:

> **[Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)**

My setup in Pivot Table is:

[image]

1. Field `Company` into rows section
2. Field `Year` into Columns Section
3. Field 'Amount' into Values section
4. **IMPORTANT**: Field `Amount` must change setup. Change option *show values as* and choose *% difference with previous year*

[image]

[image]